# telebot как поймать то что пользователь вышел из телеграм канала

Tags: python, telebot, telegram

channel="@группы, все работает"
Хочу удалить диалог бота с пользователем как только он выйдет из телеграм канала, сделал вот такую штуку но она выдает ошибку:

```
@bot.leave_chat(chat_id=channel)
def mes(message):
    m=message.id
    while True:
        try:
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, m)
            m=m-1
        except:
            break
```

Ошибка:

```
def mes(message):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

так же пробовал через `content_types=["left_chat_member"]`
но он его даже не ловит

p.s: бот в канале является администратором и добавлен в него соответсвенно

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.leave_chat(chat_id=channel)
def handle_left_chat_member(message):
    m = message.id
    while True:
        try:
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, m)
            m = m - 1
        except:
            break
```

Убедитесь, что замените channel на фактический идентификатор вашего канала.

Comment: https://pytba.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.leave_chat -> `.leave_chat(` возвращает bool и заставляет самого бота покинуть канал

Comment: а как тогда отловить это событие не могли бы подсказать